# Python regex to print the match and 5 words followed by the match

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to write a regex to find the word "vinay" and 5 words following the word "vinay".

For example

sentence1 : my name is vinay.I am trying to write a regex

Regex output : vinay and I am trying to

---

sentence2: vinay is trying to find a regex. He is facing some difficulties.

Regex output: vinay is trying to find a

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `vinay ((\w+ ){5})`

**Explanation:** `(\w+ )` matches a block of characters that forms a word and `{5}` just specifies the number of repetitions that the previous expression should consider.

Comment: it works but in case of punctuations in between it fails. eg SENTENCE1 above in question description.

Comment: vinay[^\w\s]*\s+(\w+[^\w\s]*\s+){5} I think this works